# Google Apps Script - GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.update failed with error: Invalid values[1][0]

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, chatbot, slack-api

the goal is to query fields inside a JSON object . But when executed the error above is throwned. 
Dialogflow is integrated inside Slack as an App. The Google Apps Script is the web app. Here is the code:

```
    //Writes in a sheet the Slack User id
    function doPost(e) {
      //Parse incoming JSON from Dialogflow into an object
      var dialogflow = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

      //Extracts userId from Slack
      var desiredField = dialogflow.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.event.user;

      //Instantiates Sheets function
      var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();

      //Value to insert in cell
      var values = [[ desiredField]];
      valueRange.values = values;

      //Inserts value in cell
      var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'XXX-YYY-ZZZ', 'rangeReceivingData', {valueInputOption: 'RAW'});
   }
```

and here's the incoming JSON:

```
{
  "responseId": "XXX-YYY-ZZZ",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "oi",
    "action": "input.welcome",
    "parameters": {
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Oi!",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [{
      "text": {
        "text": ["Oi!"]
      }
    }],
    "outputContexts": [{
      "name": "projects/test-agent-xxyy/agent/sessions/xxx-yyy-zzz/contexts/__system_counters__",
      "parameters": {
        "no-input": 0.0,
        "no-match": 0.0
      }
    }],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/test-agent-xxyy/agent/intents/xxx-yyy-zzz",
      "displayName": "Default Welcome Intent"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,
    "languageCode": "pt-br"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "slack",
    "payload": {
      "data": {
        "event_time": "1589561467",
        "api_app_id": "xxxyyyzzz",
        "type": "event_callback",
        "event": {
          "event_ts": "1589561467.000200",
          "team": "xxxyyyzzz",
          "blocks": [{
            "type": "rich_text",
            "block_id": "xxxyyyzzz",
            "elements": [{
              "elements": [{
                "text": "oi",
                "type": "text"
              }],
              "type": "rich_text_section"
            }]
          }],
          "ts": "1589561467.000200",
          "channel_type": "im",
          "client_msg_id": "xxx-yyy-zzz",
          "text": "oi",
          "type": "message",
          "channel": "xxxyyyzzz",
          "user": "T1H2E3G4O5A6L7"
        },
        "authed_users": ["XXXYYYZZZ"],
        "event_id": "xxxyyyzzz",
        "token": "xxxyyyzzz",
        "team_id": "xxxyyyzzz"
      }
    }
  },
  "session": "projects/test-agent-xxyy/agent/sessions/xxx-yyy-zzz"
}
```

also, the fulfillment response in dialogflow have this weird formating:

```
fields {
    key: &quot;action&quot;
    value {
      string_value: &quot;input.welcome&quot;
    }
  } ... (this is inside the sheets api error response)
```

When debuging it was possible to query the `respondeId` field (the first field from the incoming JSON). It looks that the program is taking lots of processing time on queryng further fields and in the end it throws the error. Any suggestion?

Documentation references:

- [Writing in Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values?authuser=1#writing)
- [Handling POST requests in apps scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)
- [Dialogflow documentation on webhooks](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your script, when `the incoming JSON` is `e.postData.contents`, `dialogflow.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.event.user` is `T1H2E3G4O5A6L7`. And `valueRange` is `{"values":[["T1H2E3G4O5A6L7"]]}`. In this case, I think that no error occurs. So can you confirm the value of `valueRange` by putting `Logger.log(valueRange)` after the line of `valueRange.values = values;`? By this, I would like to check it. By the way, in your script, `XXX-YYY-ZZZ` and `rangeReceivingData` are the Spreadsheet ID and the sheet name, respectively. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The range is supposed to be in A1 Notation.

Comment: @Tanaike your understanding is right. The `Logger.log(value)` would only return a value when executed via apps script editor but maybe testing is only possible via webhook (in this case), that's why the sheets is the output. Now the error message changed: `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;event&#39; of undefined ` . It's late here in Brazil, bedtime. Tomorrow i'll keep thinking about it. Any progress will be reported here. ありがとう

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you retrieve values when webhook runs "doPost", how about putting `SpreadsheetApp.openById(logSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([e.postData.contents, JSON.stringify(valueRange)])` after the line of `valueRange.values = values;`? By this, webhook runs "doPost", you can see the values of `e.postData.contents` and `valueRange` at the Spreadsheet of `logSpreadsheetId`. Using this, can you confirm the values? When such new error message is shown and `e.postData.contents` is the value using like `key: &quot;action&quot;`, it is required to replace `&quot;` to `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error, solved. First, point: 
 It was possible to recover the received `JSON` from the webhook by using `JSON.stringify`:

```
function doPost(e) {
  //Parse incoming JSON from Dialogflow
  var dialogflow = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  //Stringify webhook after parsing
  var desiredField = JSON.stringify(dialogflow);

  //Outputs value in sheet
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();

  //Value to insert in cell
  var values = [[ desiredField]];
  valueRange.values = values;

  //Inserts value in cell
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'spreadSheetId', 'range', 
     {valueInputOption: 'RAW'});
}
```

The incoming `JSON` was as expected then it was just a matter of querying the desired field:

from this:

```
  //Stringify webhook after parsing
  var desiredField = JSON.stringify(dialogflow);
```

to this:

```
 //Extracts userId from Slack
 var desiredField = dialogflow.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.event.user;
```

Error solved!

Comment: Thanks. Stringify solves the case you want more than one item in a list like this example. https://www.bpwebs.com/crud-operations-on-google-sheets-with-online-forms/